# JPG not loading in Android only

Tags: php, android, http, jpeg, charles-proxy

I have been resampling images via imagemagick on a windows machine.  Vast majority work fine however there are one or two images that won't load on any android device.  I thought it was my java app code that was broken but I can reproduce it in Chrome on the Android device too.

The images load fine on iOS/PC/Mac only just not on android.  It's only 320x44 pixels in 10Kb of data and not seeing any error messages, can anyone shed some light on what I may have done (or steps I've missed) when using imagemagick to get this to work?

Here's the link to the JPG

http://gatherhelp.com/tests/corruptjpg/broken.jpg

*UPDATE* I've used 'Charles' to intercept the network traffic from the phone and view this request and that too shows I am indeed being delivered a white image as a response to this URL from the android.

I'm using PHP on the server but JPG files are not processed, merely straight through file served

Comment: any code you have try.??

Comment: Don't need any code for this, just open it in a browser.  I am using Java and ObjectiveC in my code to load it but I don't think this is important as I can reproduce the error by just loading the URL in a web browser on the phones.

Comment: means you want this image display in browser ..?

Comment: I just mean if I can get the browser to show it I'm certain my app will.  There's something fishy with the JPG itself but I can't figure out what.  If I resave the image as a BMP and resave it back to JPG it works fine... I'm guessing it's probably something to do with exif or the likes but really not sure and why it only happens on a few images.

Comment: Does a HelloWorld+this_image app show the image?

Comment: I think I've found it, the JPG is using CMYK color space that Android's don't seem to be able to load.  Changing it to RGB via imagemagic -colorspace RGB does the trick... any idea if this is a hack or if android just doesn't support jpg fully?

Comment: At least EXIF rotation is not fully supported: that is, when you application reads it, it is your code that must rotate the image.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I know it's poor form to answer your own question but just in case this helps anyone else...
It appears that the issue was I converted some PSD and other files that were originally made for printing and had the CMYK color format instead of RGB.

To find this out I used ImageMagick's Identify command and did this

```
   Identify -verbose broken.jpg
```

giving

```
Image: broken.jpg
  Format: JPEG (Joint Photographic Experts Group JFIF format)
  Class: DirectClass
  Geometry: 256x256+0+0
  Resolution: 250x250
  Print size: 1.024x1.024
  Units: PixelsPerInch
  Type: ColorSeparation
  Endianess: Undefined
  Colorspace: CMYK
  Depth: 8-bit
```

This showed the colorspace was CMYK so a quick test of the other broken images showed they all had the same issue.
To convert them again ImageMagick to the rescue and used

```
   convert broken.jpg -colorspace RGB fixed.jpg
```

So it appears iOS/PC/Mac all support JPEGs that have CMYK but Android appears not to or at least not all CMYK images (As of Android 4.2)

Comment: It's not considered poor form to [answer your own question](http://stackoverflow.com/help/self-answer), it might help others having the same issue.