# Can I use jpg for Android/iOS splash screens?

Tags: android, ios, react-native

In the correct resolution, my splash PNG is 7mb which is humongous.

As a JPG it's under a tenth of the size, but Android won't accept it. Is there any way around this? There's no need for it to be that big.

Comment: If it's optimized with something like https://tinypng.com is it still that big?

Comment: Could be related to https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21090035/jpg-not-loading-in-android-only

Answer (score 0):

Instead of using PNG or JPG files, you can use the WebP file format (min API level 13). The WebP format provides lossy compression (like JPEG) as well as transparency (like PNG) but can provide better compression than either JPEG or PNG.

You can convert existing BMP, JPG, PNG or static GIF images to WebP format using Android Studio. For more information, see [Create WebP Images Using Android Studio](https://developer.android.com/studio/write/convert-webp).